# Entity Framework vs. nHibernate for Performance, Learning Curve overall features

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I know this has been asked several times and I have read all the posts as well but they all are very old. And considering there have been advancements in versions and releases, I am hoping there might be fresh views.

We are building a new application on ASP.NET MVC and need to finalize on an ORM tool. We have never used ORM before and have pretty much boiled down to two - nHibernate & Entity Framework.

I really need some advice from someone who has used both these tools and can recommend based on experience. There are three points that I am focusing on to finalize -

1. Performance
2. Learning Curve
3. Overall Capability

Your advice will be highly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Comment: .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0?  I would recommend you stay away from EF 1.0/3.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use Nhibernate.  I would pickup [Sharp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/) as a great framework that wraps NHibernate, ASP.NET MVC and a bunch of other open-source tools into a coherent whole that will give you a solid architectural foundation.

Nhibernate is more mature than EF4.  It is well supported by the community.  As long as you are willing to get your hands dirty from time to time, you will like it.  It's support for LINQ is currently a little weak but it is rapidly getting better.  The learning curve is not bad, but things like session management can be a little confusing at first.  One of the reasons I like Sharp Architecture is they have all the NHibernate stuff you will need in place and plenty of guidance on how to use it properly in an ASP.NET MVC project.

EF4 has the MS stamp of approval.  It is pretty good now but still behind NHibernate.  It is a  perfectly good choice and you will find lots of docs from MS, MS support and eventually more developers that are familiar with the ins and outs.  I should also mention that the Sharp Architecture folks are adding support for EF4 to their overall framework.  They will still support NHibernate, but you will be able to use EF4 if you like.

Comment: Hey, thanks Tom for you reply. I am very inclined towards the Sharp Arcitecture. But my concern is with several articles over the internet mentioning about performance issues with nHibernate. Now I figured that if you do it right, you can probably achieve a better performance, but then again me and my team are laying our hands for the first time.

Comment: @hadi: NHibernate is not a performance problem.  The performance problem is how you use it.  For example, if you use lazy loading and loop over a huge result set accessing some property that causes a database I/O for each iteration, performance is poor.  I strongly recommend getting a copy of the Nhibernate Profiler from http://nhprof.com/ to check your access patterns and keep performance good.

Comment: Thanks mate, I think I would go ahead with nHibernate. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it takes more time to learn NHibernate.

EF provides **graphical designer**, unfortunately NHibernate doesn't have a generic designer. BTW it's not a problem. If you design in domain-driven (DDD) manner, you will design your entities first and you don't care about database structure (as you used to), NHibernate will handle that for you.

**EF 4 got closer to NHibernate**. I wouldn't start working with EF 3.5, it lacks a lot of features.

If you think NHibernate is too complicated at first sight, you can **start with frameworks built on top of NHibernate**. ActiveRecords and Sharp Architect are good examples.

AFAIR **EF 3.5 supported only SQL Server 2000**. It couldn't handle the new data types from SQL Server 2005. I have no information on EF 4 but I suppose it support these improvements.

If you use NHibernate in real word applications, you have to **build an infrastructure**. E.g. I implemented the *Unit of Work and Repository patterns* to be able to write tests and create layers in my application. You have to expect the same using EF. **Detaching and attaching entities** in EF 3.5 was not an easy thing, I had to write tricky extension methods to mark fields dirty and so on. I hope they solved it in EF 4. There is no such problem with NHibernate.

You don't have to write HQL queries in NHibernate, you can use the **LINQ provider**. I think it's very important. :)

All in all **NHibernate is a mature product with good community and commercial support**. EF is young but strongly supported by Microsoft. Oh, and EF is a Microsoft-only thing while you can port your NHibernate knowledge to Java as well. It this counts for you.

Comment: NHibernate has a graphical designer.

Comment: I'm working with SQLite and I don't know about graphical designers supporting it. Please post a link, I would love to use it.
I'd like to find a designer that can reverse-engineer a database schema to entity mapping for most of the supported DBs (including SQLite).

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to look into this...
After building apps into both, NHibernate is definitely more powerful, but it's also quite clunky where EF is very clean.  And after working with Rails/ActiveRecord, both are very feature rich in comparison, so either would definitely work!

I noticed that NHibernate keeps track of what it just ran, and if it just ran a statement, it doesn't exectute it again, so a properly designed app will run minimal database statements.  I know that EF is not exactly slow either, but I'm not sure if it caches statements and results in the same way.  For a large app, this could save some database resources!

So in short, NHibernate for functionality and configurability, and EF 4.0 for cleanliness and a quick easy learning curve.  Also, one should expect EF in the next version or two should may catch up to or surpass NHibernate in functionality too, so it may make sense to have some familiarity with both.

Answer (score 0):

just take a look at this
http://gregdoesit.com/2009/08/nhibernate-vs-entity-framework-a-performance-test/